# Spring Integration MessageChannel ID

Tags: spring-integration

I need to dynamically assign messages to MessageChannels in my Spring Integration Context.
I can do this by getting the MessageChannel bean from the context when I know the names of the MessageChannel I want.

What I need to do is programatically find the name/id of the message channel(s) that are set in my ChannelAdapter/Service.

However, the MessageChannel API does not have a getName() or getId() method associated with it.

Is there a way to find this piece of information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take look at this task from other side!

What is the reason to get deal with such low API like channels?

Why just don't use the [`Router`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html) pattern on the matter?

If I understand correctly, you want to have some dinamic routing, where you determine a destination channel by some `Message` property.

So it might be enough just use an `expression` router:

```
<int:router input-channel="input" expression="payload.theChannel"/>
```